# Checking if a solution set of linear equations is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, solution-verification

> Given the following SLE:
>
> \begin{cases} x + 2y + -2z +w =0 \\ x +2y - 3w=0\end{cases} Check if
>   its solution set is a subspace find its basis.

Reason I posted here is that it's the first time I get such a question and I am not sure of my methodology.

What I did:

I set-up the following coefficients matrix:
\begin{equation*}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2 & -2 & 1   \\
1 & 2 & 0& -3 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This can be reduce into:

\begin{equation*}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2 & -2 & 1   \\
0 & 0 & 1& -2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

So we get the following:
$x+2y-2z+w=0$ and $y-2w=0 \Longrightarrow y=2w$, so in the first equation becomes $x-2z+5w=0$, any vectors $(x,y,z,w)$ with $x-2z+5w=0$ will still hold this property after vector addition and scalar multiplication hence they form a vector subspace of $R^4$.

Concerning the second part, a typical vector in this subspace is of the form $z(2,0,1,0)+w(-5,2,0,1)$ so these 2 vectors form a basis.

Is my way of approaching the problem correct, if no what else to do?

Comment: Have you already shown that the solution set of a single homogeneous linear equation is a subspace? If so, then the first part is almost trivial: the solution set for a system of homogeneous linear equations is the intersection of the individual subspaces, which is again a subspace.

Comment: No I haven't, but I will do this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a little miscalculation, the rest of your reasoning is otherwise correct. After reducing the matrix your two equations read

\begin{align}
x + 2y - 2z + w &= 0, \\
z- 2w &= 0.
\end{align}

(Note the $z$ in the second equation.)

This implies $z = 2w$ and therefore $x + 2y -3w = 0$. You can now choose $y$ arbitrary and get $x = -2y + 3w$. Hence, every vector in the solution space can be represented as $(-2y + 3w, y, 2w, w)$. Now we have

$$(-2y + 3w, y, 2w, w) = y(-2, 1, 0, 0) + w(3, 0, 2, 1), $$

hence a basis is $\{ (-2, 1, 0, 0), (3, 0, 2, 1) \}$.

One little remark concerning notation: The row-reduced echelon form of $A$ should not be called $A$ again, since it is not the same matrix. They are only equivalent.

Comment: Thank you! and yes that was a typo, I usually go for $A'$